# How to set webservice endpoint address at runtime?

Tags: c#

I want to connect to a webservice url which is provided at runtime when user logs in. so i need to set Endpoint.Address in app.config at runtime.

```
EndpointIdentity spn = EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity("host/mikev-ws");
Uri uri = new Uri(txtURL.text.trim());
var address = new EndpointAddress(uri, spn);
var client = new EchoServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IEchoService", address);
client.Close();
```

I placed this code on button click ,and gets the value of uri from textbox. Code is executing correctly and then getting an error message

> "Address property on channelfactory.endpoint was null"

my app.config is:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="LoginServiceSoap" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
        <!--<endpoint address="http://localhost:3073/LoginService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"-->
           <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="LoginServiceSoap" contract="LoginService.LoginServiceSoap"
                name="LoginServiceSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627656/wcf-error-the-address-property-on-channelfactory-endpoint-was-null

Comment: no i m not using any custom binding my code in app.config is

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in a recent project, where I only wanted to set the endpoint and authentication programatically and not use the config file at all:

```
public static class ServiceClientFactory
{
    public static HttpBindingBase BuildNavisionBinding(string endpointUrl)
    {
        //http://blog.randomdust.com/index.php/2010/10/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel/
        //http://www.codeproject.com/Forums/1649/Csharp.aspx?fid=1649&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&select=3126652&tid=3121885
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate
        {
            return true;
        });

        if (endpointUrl.ToLower().StartsWith("https"))
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue - 1;
            return binding;
        }

        else
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue - 1;
            return binding;
        }
    }

    public static TClient CreateClient<TClient, TChannel>(string endpoint, string username, string password)
        where TClient : ClientBase<TChannel>
        where TChannel : class
    {
        var client = (TClient)
            Activator.CreateInstance(
                typeof (TClient),
                BuildNavisionBinding(endpoint),
                new EndpointAddress(endpoint));

        if (null == client.ClientCredentials)
            throw new Exception(
                string.Format("Error initializing [{0}] client.  Client Credentials object was null",
                    typeof(TClient).Name));

        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential =
            new NetworkCredential(
                username,
                password);

        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
            TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;

        client.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4, 0);
        client.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 4, 0);
        client.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4, 0);

        return client;
    }
```

So from your example:

```
var client = ServiceClientFactory.CreateClient<EchoServiceClient, IEchoServicePort(txtUrl.text.trim(), /* authentication */);
```